# Display href tags as links dynamically from xml input via XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

We have input XML which is having list of sentences. Some of these sentences having links. We need to display the sentence with the links as urls, when we passed to the XSLT.

Eg:
*Please <a href="https://www.google.com>click here to start the search.*

Link can be anywhere in the sentence, it can be in the begin, middle or at the end.

Eg2:
*To begin the search, please <a href="https://www.google.com>click here.*

For the static text, we are able to achieve it using basic-link external-destination tag.

But we need to modify / have similar approach for the dynamic text

We are using XSLT version 1.0

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing a sample input, the expected output (also as code) and your current attempt.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what XSLT stylesheets are doing all the time, so unless you provide more detail, it's hard to see what your problem is.